# Is there a faster way to dissolve?

Tags: modeling

Often times, I use myself using the `dissolve` vertices/dissolve edges/dissolve faces commands far more often than the `delete` version.

I want to remap the keybinds so that instead of pressing V, E or F to delete the vertex/edge/face, I dissolve them instead.

Of course, I know this can probably be done manually by changing all the keyboard shortcuts somewhere in blender, but that is cumbersome and frankly alot of work.

I was wondering if there was an `addon` that just instantly does this swap, or alternatively, offers some sort of intuitive floating menu system like the popular Machin3Tools extension does for it's edit menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster solution I have found to quickly dissolve geometry is to use the `Ctrl + X` Dissolve Command.

Just simply select the geometry you want to dissolve, whether that be a `vertex` or an `edge`, then press `Ctrl + X` and it'll dissolve instantly.

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to are not hotkeys per say, they are menus quick access:
Every item in every menu in Blender is assigned a key when that menu is active. AFAIK the key assignement is either hardcoded in Blender in some cases, or is arbitrarily assigned by order of appearance in the menu and alphabetical order in letter.

I don't think there is an addon that changes that. However, you can absolutely customize the keymap to call directly each options in that menu. The difference is that you won't be able to isolate them into only when that menu is open.

To do so, you can simply right click a menu's element and click "Assign shortcut".

Comment: You can also right-click and add them to the Quick Menu. Then press 'Q' and they'll be instantly available on a popup menu.